# Pyparsing: Parse nested, typed parameter list with nestedExpr

Tags: python, nested, pyparsing

I have a typed and optionally nested parameter list to parse.

```
Input:
(int:1, float:3, list:(float:4, int:5))

Expected Dump:
[[['int', '1'], ['float', '3'], ['list', [['float', '4'], ['int', '5']]]]]
```

If the type is omitted, depending of the following value a standard type should be chosen:

```
Input:
(1, float:3, (4, int:5))

Expected Dump:
[[['str', '1'], ['float', '3'], ['tuple', [['str', '4'], ['int', '5']]]]]
```

As you might expect I will use the types in a parseAction to transform the values automatically during the parsing. But this step already works, hence I skip it here.

My approach of this problem is:

```
import pyparsing as pp

diCastTypes={
    "str": lambda value: value,
    "int": lambda value: int(value),
    "float": lambda value: float(value), 
    "tuple": lambda value: tuple(value),
    "list": lambda value: list(value),
    "set": lambda value: set(value),
    "dict": lambda value: dict(value),
}

bsQuoted = lambda expr : pp.Literal('\\').suppress() + expr

def parsingString (specialSigns = '', printables = pp.printables):
    seSpecialSigns = set(specialSigns).union(set('\\'))
    signs = ''.join(sorted(set(printables).difference(seSpecialSigns)))
    allowedLiterals = (
        pp.Literal(r"\t").setParseAction(lambda : "\t")      |
        pp.Literal(r"\ ").setParseAction(lambda : " ")       | 
        pp.Literal(r"\n").setParseAction(lambda : "\n")      | 
        pp.Word(signs)                                       |
        bsQuoted('"')                                        | 
        bsQuoted("'")
    )
    for special in seSpecialSigns:
        allowedLiterals = allowedLiterals | bsQuoted(special)           
    return pp.Combine(pp.OneOrMore(allowedLiterals))

value = parsingString('(),=:')
nestedValue = pp.Forward()
castPattern = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "str")("castType")
castPatternSeq = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "tuple")("castType")
parameterValue = pp.nestedExpr(content=(
    pp.Group( 
        (castPattern + value("rawValue")) | 
        (castPatternSeq + nestedValue)
    ) | 
    pp.Literal(',').suppress()
))
nestedValue <<= parameterValue
```

This implementation works almost correctly, but I have a serious problem with the default values of my nested sequences:

```
parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, float:3, list:(float:4, int:5))').dump()
"[[['int', '1'], ['float', '3'], ['list', [['float', '4'], ['int', '5']]]]]"

parameterValue.parseString('(1, float:3, (4, int:5))').dump()
"[[['str', '1'], ['float', '3'], [['str', '4'], ['int', '5']]]]"
```

As you can see, the expected default value *tuple* for the sequence is not set and the depth of the result list is not correct. I guess that `nestedExpr()` catches the pattern `(4, int:5)` before it comes through the Parser `(castPatternSeq + nestedValue)`. This problem is serious for me, because I plan to call the parserAction inside the the *nestedExpr* pattern:

```
(castPattern + value("rawValue")).setParseAction(castParameter)) | 
(castPatternSeq + nestedValue).setParseAction(castParameter))
```

This works well, if a type is given explicitly, but of course it fails otherwise.

Is there an opportunity to make `nestedExpr` a little bit less greedy?

### Update 1

Hi guys. After wasting almost a whole day yesterday, I instantly found a solution for the problem described above this morning.

I added a `delimitedList` to the implementation:

```
value = parsingString('(),=:')
nestedValue = pp.Forward()
castPattern = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "str")("castType")
castPatternSeq = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "tuple")("castType")
parameterValue = pp.nestedExpr(content=pp.delimitedList(
    pp.Group( 
        (castPattern + value("rawValue")) | 
        (castPatternSeq + nestedValue)
    )
))
nestedValue <<= parameterValue
```

This works well, but not pretty well, as you can see in the following examples:

```
parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, (int:2, int:4))').dump()
"[[['int', '1'], ['tuple', [['int', '2'], ['int', '4']]]]]"

parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, ((int:2, int:4), (int:6, int9)) )').dump()
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected ")" (at char 6), (line:1, col:7)

parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, ((int:2, int:4) (int:6, int:9)) )').dump()
"[[['int', '1'], ['tuple', [[['int', '2'], ['int', '4']], [['int', '6'], ['int', '9']]]]]]"

parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, (tuple:(int:2, int:4) tuple:(int:6, int9)) )').dump()
"[[['int', '1'], ['tuple', [['tuple', [['int', '2'], ['int', '4']]], ['tuple', [['int', '6'], ['str', 'int9']]]]]]]"
```

The exception in example 2 lets me think, that `nestedExpr` and `delimitedList` don't work very well with each other, that they're catching the pattern from each other. What ever the reason might be, this seems the all over problem, because if I omit the `,` like in example 3, the `delimitedList` has nothing to catch and the whole pattern matches. But not as I expected, because the default types are missing again. Only without `,` and with explicit types the parsing works well.

Any ideas?

### Update 2

The problem, that the statement

```
parameterValue.parseString('(int:1, ((int:2, int:4), (int:6, int9)) )').dump()
```

raises an exception, can be solved by altering the implementation a little bit (but this seems to be more a hack than really a solution). I've just added the expression `| pp.Literal(",").suppress()`:

```
value = parsingString('(),=:')
nestedValue = pp.Forward()
castPattern = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "str")("castType")
castPatternSeq = pp.Optional(pp.oneOf(list(diCastTypes.keys())) + pp.Literal(":").suppress(), "tuple")("castType")
parameterValue = pp.nestedExpr(content=pp.delimitedList(
    pp.Group( 
        (castPattern + value("rawValue")) | 
        (castPatternSeq + nestedValue)
    )
) | pp.Literal(",").suppress())
nestedValue <<= parameterValue
```